# URL that hooks into to Safari

Tags: ios, swift, url, safari, snapchat

I am building an app that uses a `QR Code` that someone scans via Snapchat. The link in the `QR code` is a download link that when in Safari, would allow you to download a `VCard`. But, Snapchat's `WebView` doesn't allow one to go to the download screen. Could I have it so the link pulls the user into Safari instead?

In Instagram you can use `hooks` to pull into different sections of the app. Maybe that could be done with Safari too?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks so much in advance!!

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: Why does your app use Snapchat to scan a QR code? Why not have your app scan the QR code? Then you can what you want. And no web view is required.

Comment: @rmaddy the idea is that people without the app can still access a card without having to download the app I.e. Only one person needs to have the app

Answer (score 1):

No. This is exactly what apps like Snapchat prevent. Discovering links to external content outside of their app's webview only "hurts" them.